# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when testing flask app on localhost

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, localhost, virtualenv

I created a simple html-app and want to deploy it using the flask package for python.

I run the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request

app =Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Where index.html is containing my html-app. In run this in a virtual environment containing my templates folder (containing index.html), my python app and the folder containing the python installation.

When executing the python program with above code, the terminal produces the following output (using pycharm if that is relevant):

```
...app.run(debug = True)
...
 * Serving Flask app "<input>" (lazy loading)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

When now trying to access the web-app via localhost:5000 (default port) I receive the following error:

```
The website can't be reached. Localhost refused the connection.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This error message is taken from chrome but other browsers return a similar message. The same is true when specifying an alternative port via

```
app.run(debug = True, port=xxxx)
```

I did not modify my hosts file.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas for troubleshooting.

Best,
Henry

Answer (score -1):

Try this at the end of your file, probably the server is not externally visible

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: I thought this is only necessary when accessing the app from a different device than the one where I am running it. I test this currently so I do not want it to be available to the public yet..